# the_content filter not working when Jetpack activated. Any idea?

Tags: filters, templates, the-content, plugin-jetpack

I use this function to filter some posts content:

```
function frontend_wizard_content($content){

    if ( !is_page(213) ) return $content;

    ob_start();
    locate_template('mycontent.php', true);
    $wizard = ob_get_clean();

    //print_r($wizard); //works (prints what I want to)
    //return "foo"; //works
    //return $wizard; //does not work
    return $wizard . $content //does not work (returns only initial content)
}


add_filter( 'the_content','frontend_wizard_content');
```

I can't understand why, but I don't get the *$wizard* variable outputted.
I did notice that this only happens when Jetpack is enabled.

**EDIT** Seems that this is not related to *the_content* filter:

My function uses [locate_template( $template_names, $load, $require_once )](https://codex.wordpress.org/locate_template).
By default, *$require_once* is *true*.

It seems that Jetpack already calls my filter upstream, since when I set 
$require_once to false, I GOT my output.
Not very handy though.

Any advices on this ?

Thanks !

Comment: from where comes the variable `$this` at the first test ?

Comment: Mhh I made the function simpler for the example, but it is defined.

Comment: require_once does not relate to calling the filter but including the template. i don;t understand why this is an issue either way, though, if you are getting your output.

Comment: The problem is that my code (my plugin) does not react the same way when Jetpack is enabled or not, which makes me think that there is some logical problems in their code.

Comment: @gordie Have you tried setting a priority on your add_filter? JetPack is a highly developed plugin, so I'm guessing the problem is in your code, not theirs.